# Can missing fonts be added to a collaborated Keynote file viewed on iCloud.com?

Tags: icloud, font, keynote

Sometimes it is very helpful to collaborate  a Keynote file with somebody who does not work on a Mac but on a Windows PC.

However, when using non-standard  fonts (e.g. Graphik) the layout of the presentation goes hay wire as the font is not supported, when viewing the file on iCloud.com.

This seems the case even when the person has the correct font (e.g. Graphik) installed on their computer.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Very interesting. Does the font display correctly in iCloud.com on a Mac, with or without the font installed?

Comment: In my experience, it is always incorrectly displayed - Mac or no Mac — when the font is different from the standard fonts. So I am curious is somebody has a solution for that.